# Trying to use Hyperledger Fabric in Azure and hangs on initial setup

Tags: azure, hyperledger-fabric

I am new to Azure.  I got my account set up, signed in, selected + (New) and Blockchain ... then "See all" ... then selected the new "HyperLedger Fabric Single Member".  Under "Select a Deployment Model" box was gray as it appears "Resource Manager" is only option.  I select "Create" and it brings up a new window with the marquis dots (3 dots flowing varying in who is lit and who is not ... ad infinitem).  That never comes back.  Pretty sure it's not provisioning as it has not asked me any questions (I know config is limited, but I expected to get a question or 2 ... how to name things if nothing else).  I am running on RHEL 7.3 and using the Firefox browser.  Are those an issue w/Azure?  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution.  Don't use Firefox, use chrome.  Problem went away as mysteriously at it showed up.